# How to "shift" only one element on array using index

Tags: java, json, spring, jolt

My input JSON looks like:

```json
{
  "id": "eea1c86e-e4e2-36df-a775-ad44a6d2d94e",
  "d": {
    "flag": 0,
    "a0": [
      {
        "a1": 0,
        "a2": -1,
        "a3": 7
      },
      {
        "a1": 2,
        "a2": -3,
        "a3": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to transform it to:

```json
{
  "dg" : {
    "gi" : 7          //7 is from d.a0.[first element from array].a3
  }
}
```

So i write spec like this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "d": {
        "a0": {
          "[0]": {
            "a3": "dg.gi"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Java code:

```
List<Object> specs = JsonUtils.classpathToList(spec);
Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
// transform the message
return (Map<String, Object>) chainr.transform(inputJSON);
```

But it returns null and I don't know why

I'm new to Jolt so I don't have much knowledge about it

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can replace **`[0]`** with **`0`**. eg. convert to

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "d": {
        "a0": {
          "0": { // only the first index of the array "a0"
                 // btw, "*" might have been used if needed to represent all indexes
            "a3": "dg.gi"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The level, *where* **`"[0]": {`** *resides currently* , represents the indexes of the array a0 and we picked only the first ( the one with index **0** ) of them.

**demo 1** (  on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ ) :

[image]

But, yet the **`"[0]"`** representation might be used by prefixing the whole path with a **`@`** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@d.a0.[0].a3": "dg.gi"
    }
  }
]
```

in order to get exactly the same result.

**demo 2** :

[image]

Comment: could you explain detail about difference between "0" and "[0]"? Thank you

Comment: Hi @SoT . the `[0]` might be used as a path element within a `@` preceded expression, while `0` in this case,  which could be a single integer or an asterisk to stand for whole indexes(eg. 0,1,2,... ) , represents the index of the nesting  array(`a0`), eg. first element of the array. Thank you too.